# Randomly throwing MongoPoolClearedError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with my database.
I frequently (several time a day) have crash during queries. It throws this error:

```
PoolClearedError [MongoPoolClearedError]: Connection pool for db2.prod.someDomain.com:27017 was cleared because another operation failed with: "connection <monitor> to [ip:v6:add:ress::]:27017 timed out"
    at ConnectionPool.processWaitQueue (/var/www/api/prod/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:520:82)
    at ConnectionPool.clear (/var/www/api/prod/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:251:14)
    at updateServers (/var/www/api/prod/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:461:29)
    at Topology.serverUpdateHandler (/var/www/api/prod/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:332:9)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/var/www/api/prod/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:444:77)
    at Server.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Server.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at markServerUnknown (/var/www/api/prod/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/server.js:298:12)
    at Monitor.<anonymous> (/var/www/api/prod/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/server.js:58:46)
    at Monitor.emit (node:events:513:28) {
  address: 'db.prod.someDomain.com:27017',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'RetryableWriteError' }
}
```

I’ve tried several changes, from decreasing my write rates and read rates over the db, but can’t get why it’s crashing … I can’t reproduce the bug, since it happens randomly, and when i read my server monitoring informations, CPUs RAM and SSD I/O are at low levels

Here is my configuration :

```
mongoose last version
mongodb js driver last version
mongodb last version
1 replicaset with 2 nodes
Each node has 32GO ram + 12 core Xeon processor
Full database size is around 130GO, biggest collection has 70M doccuments, total index size is around 24GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what is causing this error, and share it here if anybody is in my situation.

In fact the problem does not come from my database neither from my network ... but from my client server.

Sometimes my client server get its CPU overloaded, all cores going to 100%. In those cases i guess it can't handle in time its mongoDB requests which leads to this MongoPoolClearedError.

Anyone having this error should check on client side if the server is not overloaded.